# How to check socket.io connection locally?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

My app is in browser, which connects to socket.io server, it works fine, but, when client disconnect for a while ( sleep for example ) , the connection will be automatically closed by server, this is the default behavior for socket.io

How can I re-establish the connection at client side without refreshing the page? is there a status that would tell me that connection is currently off at client side? so that I re-connect when necessary?

I can't rely on an event, I think I need to know if connection is on or off in an easy way locally .. well?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`socket.io` does reconnect automatically. To check if your socket is connected check `socket.socket.connected` has Boolean value. See `socket.socket.connecting` if you are trying to connect.

```
var socket = io.connect('');                 //reconnects by default
console.log(socket.socket.connected);
console.log(socket.socket.connecting);
```

Comment: this is the kind of stuff that api should show, it feels like some kind of labyrinth